# Xamarin Local Notification custom sound not playing

Tags: audio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-notifications

Currently working on implementing local notifications in my app and so far it's working exactly as intended but when attempting to replace the default sound with my sound file I no longer get any sound when the notification triggers and I cannot figure out why.

The code for the local notification:

```
    public void GetLocalNotification(string message)
    {
        Android.Net.Uri sound = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + Application.Context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.alarm);

        // Build the notification:
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)                    // Dismiss from the notif. area when clicked
            .SetContentTitle("Notification")      // Set its title
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)  // Display this icon
            .SetDefaults(1 | 2) //Sets sound and vibration
            .SetSound(sound)
            .SetContentText(String.Format(
                message)); // The message to display.

        // Finally, publish the notification:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());
    }
```

Comment: Did you verify the sound can be found on the path where you expect it?

Comment: It is in the folder and as far as I can tell when the app runs the code returns the correct resource ID

Comment: @MortenJPetersen your code works well , what file format you use inside raw , Is it alarm.mp3 ?

Comment: @Janmejoy yeah it's an mp3

Comment: Try to set the SetDefaults(0); to zero

Comment: @GeraldVersluis works like a charm. I'd tried deleting it rather than setting it to 0 but that clearly wasn't good enough. Thanks! If you want to make it an official answer I'll be happy to upvote and accept

Comment: Great! Done :) Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939793/xamarin-android-use-setsound-for-notification-channel-to-play-custom-sound-on-no/51954845#51954845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting this line: `.SetDefaults(1 | 2) //Sets sound and vibration` to `.SetDefaults(0)`, which should stand for 'all'.

I've seen cases where this only plays sound when you set it to 0. I which I could say why, I have no clue to be honest, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

*@Gerald Versluis*: thanks, but noticed that `.SetDefaults(0)` adds sounds but then also removes vibration. So to add on this questions, do`.SetDefaults(0 | 2)`, with 2 being `(int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate`.

Thus, my solution to add sound and vibrate is:

```
.SetDefaults(0 | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
```