# Xamarin Android use SetSound for Notification Channel to play custom sound on notification

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.android, customization

I have I have been wasting at least a day trying to make this work. I am trying to play an mp3 file that i placed in Resources/raw once a notification is received. I do not know exactly how to get the Uri. My questions please are:

1.To play a custom file do you have to place it in Resources/raw or  can it be also in Assets/Sounds under the Xamarin Android project.

2.How do i get the Uri correctly based on where the mp3 file resides.

This is my code:

```
private void createNotificationChannel()
        {
            var channelName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent);
            var channelDescription = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent_description);

            // set the vibration patterm for the channel
            long[] vibrationPattern = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 };

            // Creating an Audio Attribute
            var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Alarm).Build();

            // Create the uri for the alarm file
            var alarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("MyApp.Android/Resources/raw/alarm.mp3");   // this must be wrong because its not working


            // create chan1  which is the urgent notifications channel
            var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationImportance.High)
            {
                Description = channelDescription
            };


            // set the channel properties
            chan1.EnableLights(true);
            chan1.LightColor = Color.Red;
            chan1.EnableVibration(true);   
            chan1.SetVibrationPattern(vibrationPattern);
            chan1.SetSound(alarmUri, alarmAttributes);
            chan1.SetBypassDnd(true);
            chan1.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;


            var manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can downvote but still answer the question. I have been looking this up online including the Xamarin Documentation but there was no clear answer and many other people have asked this question. Its not my question that is not being helpful in this case, its the downvoting. So I downvote that downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out and I hope this will help someone better than getting a downvote for a question, this is how you do it:
(Note: Make sure you put your mp3 file in your Xamarin Android project under **Resources/raw/soundFile.mp3**  and build the file as **Android Resource**).

Then create the Uri like this:

```
Android.Net.Uri alarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(${ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{Context.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.soundFile}");
```

Create the Alarm Attributes like this:

```
var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
               .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
               .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();
```

And finally **setSound on the channel itself** ONLY from Android Oreo onwards (not on the notification, create the channel at application launch):

```
chan1.SetSound (alarmUri, alarmAttributes);
```

Answer (score 2):

uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(
"android.resource://" + Application.Context.PackageName + "/raw/sound2");

only change I had to make.  to Fredsomofspeech answer.

android 9. 
visualstudio 2019 xamarin.forms mobile ios android. sound2.mp3

was running a file android could not play, so make sure download a mp3 file for testing verified to work.

Comment: please explain your answer bit more.